# Tomcat Threadpooling at deployment level?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, workmanagers

**Problem**: Limit the number of threads for each deployed application in a tomcat container.  So that no one deployed component can hog all the resources.

In the weblogic world I used workmanagers with a min and max thread constraint, then for each deployment specified the workmanager for that application.

I have read about *Executors* which can set thread constraints; but only at *Connector* level.  One silly trick available is making sure my clients use different ports for a single tomcat instance, and then organizing different *Executors* for each *Connector*, but that seems inefficient.

**Question**: Are there better solutions than the silly idea proposed?

**Example**

deploymentA should be allocated minimum 5 threads and maximum 10 threads

deploymentB should be allocated minimum 10 threads and maximum 50 threads

**Silly Solution**

```
<Executor name="exeOne" maxThreads="10" minSpareThreads="5" maxQueueSize="10" />
<Executor name="exeTwo" maxThreads="50" minSpareThreads="10" maxQueueSize="10" />
<Connector port="11400" executor="exeOne" />
<Connector port="11500" executor="exeTwo" />
```

Have clients/users of deploymentA call port 11400 only.  Have clients/users of deploymentB call port 11500 only.